# Is there a way to add quotes to a list with commas?

Tags: r

I have a long list from a different source, for example:

```
c(moses, abi, yoyoma)
```

I want to have it as an object:

```
a <- c("moses", "abi", "yoyoma")
```

Is there a way to do that without manually adding the quotes to each name?

Thanks.

Comment: `cc <- function(...) sapply(substitute(...()), as.character); cc(moses, abi, yoyoma)`

Comment: `First`, it is not a list. It is a vector of values when you use `c`. And, when you read them into R from a file, they are read as character vector. If they don't you can always use `as.character` to convert them.

Comment: Or `as.character(substitute(c(moses, abi, yoyoma)))[-1]`

Comment: Thanks all. @RichardScriven could that somehow work with two names? e.g., (moses, abi, yoyo cohen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick way would be

```
cc <- function(...) sapply(substitute(...()), as.character)

cc(moses, abi, yoyoma)
# [1] "moses"  "abi"    "yoyoma"
```

A more flexible solution might be

```
cc <- function(..., simplify = TRUE, evaluate = FALSE) {
  l <- eval(substitute(alist(...)))
  ev <- if (evaluate) eval else identity
  sapply(l, function(x) if (is.symbol(x)) as.character(x) else ev(x), simplify = simplify)
}

cc(moses, abi, yoyoma)
# [1] "moses"  "abi"    "yoyoma"


cc(one, two, 'three', four = 4)
#                          four 
# "one"   "two" "three"     "4" 

cc(one, two, 'three something' = rnorm(5), four = 4, simplify = FALSE)
# [[1]]
# [1] "one"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "two"
# 
# $`three something`
# rnorm(5)
# 
# $four
# [1] 4

cc(one, two, 'three something' = rnorm(5), four = 4, simplify = FALSE, evaluate = TRUE)
# [[1]]
# [1] "one"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "two"
# 
# $`three something`
# [1] -1.1803114  0.3940908 -0.2296465 -0.2818132  1.3744525
# 
# $four
# [1] 4
```

Comment: hanks a lot. Is there a way to work with two names?                                  e.g., (moses, abi, yoyo cohen)

Comment: @RamB not that I can think of outside making changes to the parser

Answer (score 1):

Just use function as.character()

```
as.character(a)
 [1] "moses"  "abi"    "yoyoma"
```